# Correct pulling edxops/forums way

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, edx, openedx

I'm making my own devstack for works with `OpenEdx`.

I pulled the official `devstack` repository from edx and I'm modifying it.

I'm trying add `forums` to my stack but I can't run in since docker compose.

I added this to `composer` file:

```
forums:
    command: bash -c 'source /edx/app/forum/cs_comments_service_env && ruby app.rb -p 18080'
    container_name: edx.devstack.forums
    depends_on:
      #   - xqueue:xqueue
      - mongo
      - elasticsearch
      # - rabbitmq:rabbitmq
      - mysql
      - memcached
    environment:
      CACHE_LOCATION: edx.devstack.memcached:12211
      DB_HOST: edx.devstack.mysql
      TEST_ELASTICSEARCH_URL: "http://edx.devstack.elasticsearch:9200"
    image: edxops/forums:latest
    ports:
      - 4567:4567
```

I'm confuse about which the correct command in run:

```
studio:
    command: bash -c 'source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env && python /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/manage.py cms runserver 0.0.0.0:18010 --settings devstack_docker'
```

This is the command for studio.

```
forums:
    command: bash -c 'source /edx/app/forum/cs_comments_service_env && ruby app.rb -p 18080'
```

I tried with this but the folder doesn't exist.

So I tried with: `command: bash -c 'ruby app.rb -p 18080'` but I get this error:

> edx.devstack.forums | bash: ruby: command not found
> edx.devstack.forums exited with code 127

So, I'm confused about the `forums` image and about how can I provide it so that it works correctly.

Can anyone help me?

- How provide it?
- How run it(command)?

**UPDATE:**

I have a new configuration:

```
forums:
    command: bash -c 'cd /edx/app/forum/cs_comments_service && exec /edx/app/forum/cs_comments_service/bin/unicorn -c config/unicorn_tcp.rb'
    container_name: edx.devstack.forums
    depends_on:
      # - xqueue:xqueue
      - mongo
      - elasticsearch
      # - rabbitmq:rabbitmq
      - mysql
      - memcached
    environment:
      CACHE_LOCATION: edx.devstack.memcached:12211
      DB_HOST: edx.devstack.mysql
      SEARCH_SERVER: "http://edx.devstack.elasticsearch:9200"
      TEST_ELASTICSEARCH_URL: "http://edx.devstack.elasticsearch:9200"
      MONGOHQ_URL: "mongodb://cs_comments_service:password@mongo.edx:27017/cs_comments_service"
      GEM_PATH: "/edx/app/forum/.gem"
      GEM_HOME: "/edx/app/forum/.gem"
      RBENV_ROOT: "/edx/app/forum/.rbenv"
    image: edxops/forum:latest
    ports:
      - 4567:4567
```

But I still have this issue:

```
docker-compose logs -f --tail=500 | grep edx.devstack.forums
Attaching to edx.devstack.forums, edx.devstack.chrome, edx.devstack.firefox, edx.devstack.credentials, edx.devstack.discovery, edx.devstack.elasticsearch, edx.devstack.ecommerce, edx.devstack.studio, edx.devstack.lms, edx.devstack.memcached, edx.devstack.mysql, edx.devstack.mongo
edx.devstack.forums | /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory
```

But, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I inspected the image and figured out the details that will be helpful in running the container. I will list down my findings as below:

- **[Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)**: Supervisord has been used to run the process in the container. Although the container is only running a single process I don't see a purpose of using a process manager here. So, if you are creating a local copy of the image just get rid of it. But for now leave it, the `CMD` I am providing is the right way of launching a process in a container.
- **Startup**: The startup sequence as per `CMD` of docker image is:

  ```
  docker run => supervisord => launch script
  ```

  where launch script is `/edx/app/forum/forum-supervisor.sh` responsible for :

  1. Loading environment variables from `/edx/app/forum/forum_env`.
  2. Switching the directory to `/edx/app/forum/cs_comments_service`.
  3. Starting the `unicorn` server.

Also, ruby is installed at a custom path as follow:

```
    root@8a5de1d489c5:/edx/app# which ruby 
    /edx/app/forum/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

So environment variables need to loaded to use it. The environment variables loaded as part of startup include:

```
export LISTEN_HOST="0.0.0.0"
export NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME="default_env-default_deployment-forum"
export DATA_DIR="/edx/var/forum"
export LISTEN_PORT="4567"
export MONGOHQ_URL="mongodb://cs_comments_service:password@mongo.edx:27017/cs_comments_service"
export GEM_PATH="/edx/app/forum/.gem"
export RACK_ENV="staging"
export WORKER_PROCESSES="4"
export NEW_RELIC_ENABLE="False"
export SINATRA_ENV="staging"
export SEARCH_SERVER="http://es.edx:9200"
export PATH="/edx/app/forum/cs_comments_service/bin:/edx/app/forum/.rbenv/bin:/edx/app/forum/.rbenv/shims:/edx/app/forum/.gem/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
export API_KEY="password"
export HOME="/edx/app/forum"
export GEM_HOME="/edx/app/forum/.gem"
export RBENV_ROOT="/edx/app/forum/.rbenv"
```

With this information you can run the image with required configuration.

For example set the list of variables accordingly to your configuration in the `environment` section. You will need to set all of these variables in `yml` file. Once done the `command` should be

```
bash -c 'cd /edx/app/forum/cs_comments_service && exec /edx/app/forum/cs_comments_service/bin/unicorn -c config/unicorn_tcp.rb'
```

else if you want to avoid writing all these variables just write a custom script to do it for you or launch with default command which will be married to these config.